# Вывести дробную часть положительного числа на Питоне

Tags: python, алгоритм

Дано положительное действительное число X. Выведите его дробную часть.

Вот моё решение, но оно неправильное:

```
print((int(a*1000)-(floor(a))*1000)/1000)
```

Comment: А что у вас получилось до сих пор?

Comment: print((int(a*1000)-(floor(a))*1000)/1000) получилось как-то так,но это решение неправильное

Comment: @helenmay ответ примите нажатием на галочку слева от него

Answer (score 11):

Остаток от деления на единицу, как это ни странно, даст нужный результат:

```
print (a%1)
```

Comment: >>> (15 / 8) % 1
0.875
>>> 15 / 8
1.875
Всё простое-- реально очень просто!

Comment: @AlexandrDragunkin floating point и "просто"  это несовместимо. К примеру можно подумать о поведении с отрицательным нулем `-0.0` (какой знак у дробной части?), `math.inf` (чему дробная часть должна быть равна для бесконечности?), будет ли потеря точности для subnormal величин? -- поведение `%1` и `math.modf` может отличаться.

Comment: Да уж, не всё так однозначно
>>> 15 / (- 8) % 1
0.125
>>> 15 / -8
-1.875

Наверное надо так  abs(15/-8)%1

Хотя math.modf реально надёжнее. @jfs, спасибо! >>> math.modf(15 / -8)
(-0.875, -1.0)

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы разделить число на дробную и целые части, [можно `math.modf()` использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.modf):

```
>>> import math 
>>> math.modf(1.5)
(0.5, 1.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

`print(x - int(x))` - это более точный вариант, но `print(a%1)` также сработает

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
x = float(input())
y = x-math.floor(x)
print(y)
```

И округлить по вкусу)))

Answer (score 1):

Из курса ВШЭ решал задание такое вот так:

```py
from math import *

x = float(input())
if x > 1:
    a = floor(x)
    b = x - a
    print(round(b, 2))
else:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def solution(n):
    decimal = divmod(n, 1)
    return round(list(decimal)[1], 10)

print(solution(4.1))
```

Ответом будет 0.1| divmod(n,1) разделит число n на кортеж (4.0, 0.0999999998). Дальше я просто беру число под индексом [1] , это число 0.0999999998, и затем округляю его до десятых. В итоге получается 0.1

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]