# Неправильный вывод разности действительного числа и его целой части

Tags: python, float

Здравствуйте, задача такова: вывести дробную часть числа.
мой код:

```
a = float(input())
print(a - int(a))
```

Однако при вводе числа 19.9 вывод: `0.8999999999999986`
Я знаю, что можно округлить до 0.9 при помощи round(x , y), однако хочу спросить, есть ли другой вариант решения

Comment: Попробуйте вывести в окно вывода, число которое вы отнимаете, не как `int` а как `float`, и сравните то что вы отнимаете, и то что получается на выходе. т.к. вы все таки отнимаете у `float` и то что вы определили `a` как `int` не делет его чистым `int`, вы отнимаете у `float` и он автоматически кастуется к `float`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Вывести дробную часть положительного числа на Питоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/757454/23044):

```
>>> import math
>>> math.modf(19.9)
(0.8999999999999986, 19.0)
>>> 19.9 % 1
0.8999999999999986
```

То есть результат правильный у вас в этом случае:

```
>>> 19.9 .hex()
'0x1.3e66666666666p+4'
>>> (19 + 0.9).hex()
'0x1.3e66666666666p+4'
>>> (19 + 0.8999999999999986).hex()
'0x1.3e66666666666p+4'
```

Сами числа отличаются:

```
>>> 0.9 .hex()
'0x1.ccccccccccccdp-1'
>>> 0.8999999999999986 .hex()
'0x1.cccccccccccc0p-1'
```

Как `19.9` так и `0.9` точно не представимы как числа с плавающей точкой для `sys.float_info.radix == 2`:

```
>>> float_to_bin_fixed(19.9)
'10011.11100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011'
>>> float_to_bin_fixed(.9)
'0.11100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101'
```

См. [float_to_bin_fixed()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/739574/23044).

То есть дроби периодические и точное значение дробной части в двоичной системе: **0.111(0011)<sub>2</sub>** [скобки означают бесконечное повторение].

Если хотите точное значение получить, то можно использовать десятичную систему:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> d = decimal.Decimal('19.9')
>>> d % 1
Decimal('0.9')
>>> d.radix()
Decimal('10')
```

[What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/).